# value of k in a triangle

Tags: geometry

[image]

I can easily find the base of the smaller triangle. but wjhat else need to do to determine the value of k?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: The triangles are similar.

Comment: can you write how?

Comment: Their respective angles are equal.

Comment: The triangles are similar, so that means the ratio of the first triangle $?:12:13$ is the same as the ratio of the second $?:?:k$.  They are right triangles, and you have already arrived at the length of the base, what other info do you need?

Comment: @mathphy Suppose $\theta$ is the angle between the sides of length $12$ and $13$. Then the angle between the side of length $13$ and the base must be $90^\circ-\theta$. Now because the hypotenuses are perpendicular to each other, observe that the angle between the side of length $k$ and the base must therefore be:
$$
180^\circ - 90^\circ - (90^\circ - \theta) = \theta
$$

Answer (score 2):

the 3rd side of first rt triangle by pythagorus theorem is 
$$13^2 - 12^2 = 25 = 5^2 $$ 
so third side that is the base is 5

so base of other right triangle is $12.2 - 5 = 7.2$

[image]
now by similar triangle property(AAA)

$$\frac{13}{k} = \frac{12}{7.2}$$

now find k

which is $7.8$